# Don't log some kind of exceptions

Tags: cakephp, exception, logging, cakephp-3.0

I am running a pretty big application, with a few thousand users and I like to check the log files (almost) daily, to see if something has gone wrong.

Fortunately the system is quite stable, but I am having a lot of `Invalid CSRF token`, `Record not found in table X with primary key [NULL]`, (and so on) errors. I usually ignore that kind of errors, since there is not much that I can do to avoid them.

Is there a way to tell the logger not to save those kind of exceptions in my log files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the `Error` section of your applications `app.php` configuration file, specifically the explanation for the `skipLog` option.

> [...]
>
> `skipLog` - array - List of exceptions to skip for logging. Exceptions that extend one of the listed exceptions will also be skipped for logging. E.g.:
>
> ```
> 'skipLog' => ['Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException', 'Cake\Network\Exception\UnauthorizedException']
> ```
>
> [...]

You'd want to skip `\Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException` and `\Cake\Network\Exception\InvalidCsrfTokenException`.

If you need more fine-grained control, then you'd have to create a custom error handler and override for example `BaseErrorHandler::_logException()` where you could inspect the exception and act accordingly.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Error & Exception Handling > Error & Exception Configuration](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/errors.html#error-exception-configuration)**
- **[Cookbook > Error & Exception Handling > Creating your Own Error Handler](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/errors.html#creating-your-own-error-handler)**

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!